# "KeyError: 'content-length'" when using PyTube on specific video downloads

Tags: python, pytube

I am getting the error

> KeyError: 'content-length'

while downloading videos. Specifically for this one, whenever I try to download this video in 1080p, I get the error.

**To Reproduce**

Try downloading this video in 1080p resolution with pytube.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6PDxyCLaTeU

**Code**

```
from pytube import YouTube
yt = YouTube("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6PDxyCLaTeU")

yt.streams.filter(resolution="1080p").first().download()
```

**Exception**

```
return int(head(url)["content-length"])
KeyError: 'content-length'
```

**System information**

- Python version : Python 3.9.2
- Pytube version : 12.0.0
- Command used to install pytube : pip install pytube

Comment: Looks like a bug in the library you are using. There isn't much we can do to help, you should [report the issue](https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/new?assignees=&labels=bug&template=bug_report.md&title=%5BBUG%5D) to the maintainers of PyTube. Maybe include the full backtrace when you do.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli, Yes I did create a issue in the repo of PyTube, but no response ... that's why created a question here too ... lets see what happens